# Pause/Resume YouTube in Hidden <DIV>

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-javascript-api

Thank you **Mihail Minkov** for helping me with a great foundation for the YouTube API.  Had to adjust what you gave me since I am displaying a playlist and not a single video.

The Code
HTML

```html
    <body class="center">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="/main/application.html">Application</a>
            <a href="/main/games.html">Games</a>
            <a href="/main/leadership.html">Leadership</a>
            <a href="#Social" class="active">Social Media</a>
            <a href="#Social" class="active">Social Media</a>
        </div>
        <div class="top">
            <input type="image" src="/media_files/social_media/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:100px" onclick="img(1); pauseVideo();">
            <input type="image" src="/media_files/social_media/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:100px" onclick="img(0); pauseVideo();">
        </div>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <div id="twitter" hidden>
            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="600" data-height="400" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/clanshocktac?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by clanshocktac</a>
            <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
```

JavaScript

```js
    var done = false;
    var player;
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function img(x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('twitter').style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('twitter').style.display = 'none';
        }
        return;
    }

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '600',
            width: '900',
            playerVars: {
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: 'PLDNv6o8iIDrw6ETcAy8s3xHgn2UdjpZ-e'
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }

    function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
    }

    function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
    }
```

This is the fix for the Play/Pause when I switch between the YouTube`<div>` and Twitter`<div>` problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying about the IDs is not valid. An ID works to identify a unique element. If you put the ID on two separate elements it's only going to get one of them. It would also show warnings in console.

Also, `<div align="center">` is obsolete. You should either use inline styles like `<div style="text-align: center;">` or define a class `text-center` and just apply it to the `div` like `<div class="text-center">`.

Also, from what you have shown you have static code, but with the YouTube JavaScript API you just need the `<div id="player"></div>` element and you initialize everything with JavaScript. You can see [this example here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

If I have to modify your example I would probably do something like:

**HTML**

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="image" src="/media_files/social_media/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" style="width:100px" onclick="img(1); playVideo();">
    <input type="image" src="/media_files/social_media/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:100px" onclick="img(0); stopVideo();">
</div>
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="tw" style="text-align: center;" hidden>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="600" data-height="400" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/clanshocktac?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by clanshocktac</a>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: 
      {
        listType:'playlist',
        list: 'PLDNv6o8iIDrw6ETcAy8s3xHgn2UdjpZ-e'
      }
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function playVideo() {
    player.playVideo();
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

I made a mix of what you are trying to do and the example that comes in the Youtube Player API documentation. Not sure if it's going to solve your problem, but I think you should check it out.

Comment: I appreciate the help, the code above did not work at first, however, I got it working.  Now I am trying to get the embed to stay centered.  The YouTube Player starts off in the middle of the page (center), when I go to the twitter feed the player pauses, when I go back to the YouTube embed it is aligned to the left.  This is with a separate file I am running.  I will implement it tomorrow and see if the css file I have that is live will keep it centered.

Comment: Try putting the `<div id="player"></div>` inside a centered element. You could do something like `<div style="margin: 20px auto; max-width: 1200px;"><div id="player"></div></div>`. I would recommend using a responsive embed style though.